# NHibernate Current Session Context Error "Object reference not set to instance of an object"

Tags: c#, xml, nhibernate

I want to use the NHibernate Session Context.

What I have in my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
```

But now when I try to check if a session is bound:

```
if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(mySessionFactory))
```

I get the error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object.
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at NHibernate.Context.WebSessionContext.GetMap()
   at NHibernate.Context.MapBasedSessionContext.get_Session()
   at NHibernate.Context.CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(ISessionFactory factory)
```

When I inspect the `sessionFactory` I see that the CurrentSessionContext throws an error:

[image]

I've never used CurrentSessionContext before. So I'm glad for help. Thanks!

**== EDIT ==**

Here is what I have to create the session factory:

```
public Configuration GetConfiguration()
{
    configuration = new Configuration();

    // Configure NHibernate with the hibernate.cfg.xml file 
    configuration.Configure(Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "hibernate.cfg.xml"));

    // Create new model mapper
    var mapper = new ModelMapper();

    // Get all types of the assembly and add them to the mapper
    mapper.AddMappings(assembly.GetExportedTypes());

    // Compile the mappings
    var mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

    // Add the mappings (using executing assembly)
    configuration.AddMapping(mapping);

    return configuration;
}
```

I call it by:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, ISessionFactory> sessionFactories = new Dictionary<string, ISessionFactory>();

sessionFactories.Add("hibernate.cfg.xml", GetConfiguration(assembly).BuildSessionFactory());
```

And my `OpenSession()`

```
public void OpenSession(string configFile)
{
     if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(SessionFactoryHelper.Instance.GetSessionFactoryByConfigFile(configFile)))
            throw new Exception("There is already a session bind to current context");

    // Get new session from the session factory
    var session = SessionFactoryHelper.Instance.GetSessionFactoryByConfigFile(configFile).OpenSession();

    // Start the transaction
    session.BeginTransaction();

    // Bind the session to the currentsession context
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
}
```

**== EDIT 2 ==**

As I just found out, it seems that the CurrentSessionContext throws the `NullReferenceExeption` when I try to bind the session to it...

```
CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-current-session). `NHibernate.Context.WebSessionContext` may be the one you look for.

Comment: Thank you, but if I use `<property name="current_session_context_class">NHibernate.Context.WebSessionContext</property>` I get the same error (as already shown in screenshot)

Comment: Did you bind your session to the CurrentSessionContext ? In your code there should be something like `Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.Configure();
configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
ISessionFactory sf = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
ISession session = sf.OpenSession();
CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);`

Comment: Please see my edit, how I create the sessionfactory. In that moment I expect the Session to just be `null` instead of the error. The session gets bound on .OpenSession()

Comment: Hm, in the NHibernate version 5.1 - which I have - there is no `Instance` member for `SessionFactoryHelper`. Also I would do the bind before calling `session.BeginTransaction()`